# unable to read file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to have user input an interger, based on the integer value, I am calling mix function to read in the file contents as code shows below. I am getting, this error:

```
Project2.java:43: variable urlScan might not have been initialized
                        while (urlScan.hasNext())
                               ^
Project2.java:34: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                fileScan = new Scanner (new File("input.txt"));
                       ^
```

Any ideas, what I might be doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Project2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

                System.out.println("Select an item from below: \n");
                System.out.println("(1) Mix");
                System.out.println("(2) Solve");
                System.out.println("(3) Quit");

                int input;
                Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
                input = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.println(input);  
                if(input==1) {
                    mix();
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("this is exit");
                    } 
        }




        public static void mix()
          {
                String url;
                Scanner fileScan, urlScan;
                fileScan = new Scanner (new File("input.txt"));
                // Read and process each line of the file
                while (fileScan.hasNext())
                    {
                        url = fileScan.nextLine();
                        System.out.println ("URL: " + url);
                        //urlScan = new Scanner (url);
                        //urlScan.useDelimiter("/");
                        //  Print each part of the url
                        while (urlScan.hasNext())
                        System.out.println ("   " + urlScan.next());
                        System.out.println();
                     }
            }
     }
```

Comment: The errors are pretty clear...

Comment: Have you tried Google? - [first](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+variable+might+not+have+been+initialized+stackoverflow), [second](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+unreported+exception+must+be+caught+or+declared+to+be+thrown+stackoverflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors are pretty expressive.

- Initialize your `urlScan` **local variable**(local variables don't get default values)
- Wrap the `fileScan = new Scanner (new File("input.txt"));` around `try/catch`. or declare that your method might  throw FileNotFoundException in your method signature. (new File(str) might throw `FileNotFoundException` which is a **checked exception** and compiler will force your  handled it).

Comment: Or better, since you don't know how to deal with an IOException in the mix method, declare it in the throws clause.

Answer (score 1):

First, `urlScan` isn't initialized.

Second, you should surround `fileScan = new Scanner (new File("input.txt"));` with an try/catch for `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables **must** be initialized before use, so uncomment this line:

```
urlScan = new Scanner (url);
```